# Book recommendation for Linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for suggestions, it has to be a self study book and should be able to relate to applications to real world problems.
If it is more computer science oriented , that would be great.

Comment: Have you searched for similar questions here? They have been answered with numerous, well-detailed recommendations.

Comment: yeah, but i was looking more from Computer science perspective.

Comment: Maybe the best book for Computer Science is just the best book at all, in that case I would recommend Hoffman's Linear Algebra.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/344879/2002) question is relevant.

Comment: Strang, whose book s mentioned below, has free video lectures of his course at MIT Open Courseware. This is the more "practical" LA course at MIT. On the more theoretical side, They tend to use Axler, "Linear Algebra Done Right."

Comment: @JonasGomes  this book is 50 volumes ...... do we need the fifty volumes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Linear Algebra and its Applications* by David C. Lay is a simple book containing many references to real-world problems, including computer science.

Answer (score 6):

Jim Hefferon has a freely available book [Linear Algebra](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/) that discusses various applications as well as giving a solid theoretical base.

Answer (score 5):

There is an innovative course [Coding the Matrix](http://codingthematrix.com/) offered by [Philip Klein](http://cs.brown.edu/people/klein/) which consists of a [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0615880991) and a [course](https://www.coursera.org/course/matrix) offered on Coursera and [other](https://www.class-central.com/mooc/505/coursera-coding-the-matrix-linear-algebra-through-computer-science-applications) places. It even has a [Twitter](https://twitter.com/CODINGtheMATRIX) account for keeping updated. The [reviews](http://www.topfreeclasses.com/course/7060/Coding-the-Matrix-Linear-Algebra-through-Computer-Science-Applications) are [controversial](http://www.reddit.com/comments/1frk5a), see also [here](http://www.coursetalk.com/coursera/coding-the-matrix-linear-algebra-through-computer-science-applications) and [here](http://www.quora.com/Coursera/How-close-or-far-is-the-online-course-coding-the-matrix-is-to-what-students-take-in-Brown-University-In-general-any-course-for-that-matter), but it looks as an interesting challenge to try. It is designed, according to the author's website, as a "course is to provide students interested in computer science an introduction to vectors and matrices and their use in CS applications".

Answer (score 4):

[**Linear Algebra and its Applications-** ***Gilbert Strang***](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0030105676) seems to be very recommended.

Comment: I love this book, but the $270 price tag on Amazon induces a bit of nerd rage.  The pdf can be found online.

Comment: You can get a 3rd edition of this book used for cheap if you buy the international edition: http://www.textbookrush.com/search/search-results.aspx?search=Linear+Algebra+and+its+Applications-+Gilbert+Strang&pt=0

Even though the price tag is $270, there are cheaper options.

Answer (score 3):

Strang revisited with a valid free download:

https://archive.org/details/flooved1323

"Computational Sciences and Engineering - Applied Linear Algebra"

Answer (score 2):

Linear Algebra Step by Step would be useful for understanding linear algebra;
[http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Step-Kuldeep-Singh/dp/0199654441](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199654441)

Comment: It has complete online solutions to all the problems in the book so making it ideal for self study.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the new book [Introduction to Applied Linear Algebra -- Vectors, Matrices, and Least Squares](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/vmls/) by Boyd and Vandenberghe. A PDF of the latest draft can be found on Boyd's website.

I also recommend a few books by Gilbert Strang:

1) Linear Algebra and Its Applications

2) Introduction to Linear Algebra

3) Differential Equations and Linear Algebra